# Window unit AC installation in narrow window

Tags: air-conditioning

My apartment has double hung windows, but they are quite narrow (~19.5 inches at the screen, 22 inches at the opening).  I'm currently using a portable air conditioner, but I'd really like to use a standard window fit model.

There are a variety of compact AC units available whose physical dimensions are smaller than the opening, but state they require a minimum window size larger than I have (23 inches, for say a unit that measures 18.5 inches at its widest point).  Can these units be made to fit, by say not installing the side panels? Anyone tried this and made it work?

[image]

Comment: Terrible - almost worthless picture. Do better.

Answer (score 4):

The accordion side panels should be removable (in fact the AC is probably sold with them detached to make a more compact box).  To seal the window you'll need to put something else to fill the gap between the side of the AC and the window frame.  A small piece of plywood cut to fit would probably work.